# Notebook for data science

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter, colab

I'm searching for an online Jupiter notebook environment that allows collaborating in real-time. I've found that I've choice from two services Deepnote.com and DataLore by JetBrains. I have little experience with Deepnote and it starts to perform very poorly when you have a lot of cells in your notebook. If anyone has experience with two environments, does the DataLore suffer the same issue? What advantages and disadvantages do DeepNote and DataLore have relative over each other? Are there any other real-time collaboration environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product Manager from [Deepnote](https://deepnote.com) here.

I'm sorry it doesn't perform well when the notebook is too big. We're aware of the issue, and it's quite hard to solve, but I'll stress its importance to our engineers.

I'm not sure how Datalore handles large notebooks. When you compare them, they both have some nice features (collaboration, secure integrations, reactivity). Deepnote has a few extra ones (automatic versioning, diffing, comments...), and some great ones coming soon (scheduled reports, published applications). On the other hand, JetBrains is a company with decades of experience in the IDE business.

Some other ones you can check which have an open free tier and real-time collaboration: Nextjournal, CoCalc, Databricks (community edition). There are a few more similar products listed [here](https://datasciencenotebook.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your work and hope you will fix issues with big notebooks. Also, I have some ideas about features for Deepnote which may seem interesting to you. First of all, a dark theme will be very convenient for many users. Also, I can't find projects to which I am invited anywhere, so I think there should be another list of such projects in the dashboard.

Comment: In addition to it, Find&Replace is a very useful feature of the coding environment, as well as notifications that code is executed or died (I know that this feature is available in the browser, but in messenger such as Telegram or Signal it will be more convenient). And finally, the ability to run some preliminarily chosen cells with one button will be really good.